# Issue with setting up docker for WSL based ubuntu 20.04. I want to make sure the WSL2 deep learning can use my GPU

Tags: docker, deep-learning, ubuntu-20.04, wsl-2, nvidia-docker

Hi I'm having an issue with setting up docker for a deep learning project. Im new to deep learning actually and setting it up. I realise that it works in Linux so I had to download a WSL so I downloaded ubuntu 20.04.

So I want to restart the service with systemd with the systemctl command. I'm setting up the NVIDIA Container ToolKit btw. So I type the following command thinking it can work like that.

```
$ sudo systemctl restart docker
```

So that's the first problem I had, the 2nd is I want to try and test whether this WSL can use my GPU and I typed the following command:

```
$ docker run --rm --gpus all nvidia/cuda:10.4-base nvidia-smi
```

But this was what I get back; been searching the whole internet cant find an answer that's specific to the one I had.

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:545: container init caused: Running hook #0:: error running hook: exit status 1, stdout: , stderr: nvidia-container-cli: initialization error: driver error: failed to process request: unknown.
```

Much help would be appreciated, I'm actually trying to access Alphafold2 with my own PC so this is my first time using this deep learning software and I'm having trouble with the initial installation of the requirements, been trying to solve for hours past 12am. This is important for my Final year project so I hope I can find some answers here. :) thanks for reply in advance.

Comment: If you run `nvidia-smi` by itself from the WSL terminal, what is the output?

Comment: `Failed to initialize NVML: GPU access blocked by the operating system
Failed to properly shut down NVML: GPU access blocked by the operating system`

Comment: I searched the internet and it says that its possible that I have not installed CUDA correctly, but when I checked with `sudo apt-get install cuda` it shows that I'm in the newest version (11.4.0-1)

Comment: Having cuda installed doesn't mean cuda can access the GPU. Check this out: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda/wsl

Comment: what is the shape of your instance VM or BM?  if it is VM i would be suspicious if it is in paravirtualized mode. This post goes into the details https://www.jie-tao.com/tag/wsl/